# Converting a Javascript regular expression to preg_match() compatible

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have this code from a javascript

```
/+\uFF0B0-9\uFF10-\uFF19\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9u/
```

after some read about php & \u support I convert it to \x

```
/\+\x{FF0B}0-9\x{FF10}-\x{FF19}\x{0660}-\x{0669}\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}/u
```

but still I'm not able to use it in php

```
$phoneNumber = '+911561110304';
$start = preg_match('/\+\x{FF0B}0-9\x{FF10}-\x{FF19}\x{0660}-\x{0669}\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}/u', $phoneNumber,$matches);
```

the matches will be null!

how to fix this?

Comment: You sure you copied that correctly? Shouldn't the JS regex also have character classes at least (square brackets) and some repetition modifier at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to match an ASCII plus sign or its Japanese Halfwidth equivalent, followed by one or more digits from a few different writing systems.  But, as @mario observed, you seem to be missing some square brackets.  The JavaScript version probably should be:

```
/[+\uFF0B][0-9\uFF10-\uFF19\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]+/
```

(I couldn't see any reason for the `u` at the end, so I dropped it.)  The PHP version would be:

```
'/[+\x{FF0B}][0-9\x{FF10}-\x{FF19}\x{0660}-\x{0669}\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}]+/u'
```

Of course, this will allow a mix of ASCII, Arabic and Halfwidth characters in the same number.  If that's a problem, you'll need to break it up a bit.  For example:

```
'/\+(?:[0-9]+|[\x{0660}-\x{0669}]+|[\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}]+)|\x{FF0B}[\x{FF10}-\x{FF19}]+/u'
```